# Cypress mochawesome Reporting :Getting error as 'command not found: marge', while executing the command to generate HTML report

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

`1. I have configured mochawesome depandencies and now my package.json has
following

- "mocha": "^8.3.0",
  "mochawesome": "^6.2.1",
  "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.0",
  "mochawesome-report-generator": "^5.2.0"

2. After test execution , i could able to merge the separate json reports in a folder using command

"npx mochawesome-merge Test/cypress/reports/mocha/*.json > test/cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json"

3. Now to prepare the html report from merged json, when i am trying to execute below command

"npx marge test/cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json --reportDir ./ --inline"

getting error as 'command not found: marge'

Could any one please let me know, what exactly i am doing wrong here`

Comment: Try with this method , It will work 100% https://softans.com/using-mochawesome-reporter-with-cypress/

Answer (score 2):

use `npx mochawesome-report-generator ....` instead of `npx marge ....`
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Version 4 has come with a breaking change — it no longer accepts params like `reportDir` or `rootDir`. Instead, it now accepts a list of file paths or glob patterns to source report files. If you are migrating to Version 4, you will likely have to change your params accordingly.

See a solution here: https://github.com/Antontelesh/mochawesome-merge

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.

```
ERROR: Failed to merge reports
SyntaxError: cypress/reports/output.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\usman.allaudin\CypressAutomation\node_modules\mochawesome-merge\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:33:18
    at C:\Users\usman.allaudin\CypressAutomation\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
```

There's no need to worry about this; I have a solution.
**Just replace the below code**

From

```
"merge": "mochawesome-`merge cypress/reports/*.json > cypress/reports/output.json"
```

To

```
"mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/*.json -o cypress/reports/output.json"
```